# How to rewrite subdirectory name in iis

Tags: regex, iis, iis-7.5

My website is located at:

```
example.com/NAME/home.aspx?id=1
```

I want to make it so this url works without redirecting to original:

```
example.com/DIFFERENTNAME/home.aspx?id=1
```

Also, when hitting the first url, I want it to be redirected to the 2nd.

I have url rewrite module Tried modifying several inbound rules, but cannot make it to work.

Comment: Which IIS you are using?

Comment: @DarshitShah, sorry, forgot to mention IIS 7.5

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTP Redirect and reference link follows 
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect